# can you give a example for how to pass a variable value which is come from javascript to one getter method

Tags: apex

please give me a suggestion for this

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Uma,  when asking questions it's important that you provide us with enough information so that we can understand what you're trying to do. There are several ways in which you can go from javascript to apex, are you using standard visualforce or javascript remoting ? Or are you entirely new to using  javascript in salesforce ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for this question. Its up to you decide

1. [Hidden Field](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputHidden.htm)
2. [Apex param](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_param.htm)
3. But the best way is [JavaScript Remoting](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm)